# How do I use Excel's "=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH..." function to exclude 'complicated compounded' results?

Tags: excel, colors, excel-formula, wildcard, formula

I am trying to validate a list of product descriptions to highlight any instances where the colour of the product has been used in its description.

I have a list of colours...

```
Example:
Blue
Red
Green
Yellow
Purple
etc.
```

I am using the following formula to detect if one of these colours has been used:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table1[Colors],A1)))>0,"Cannot include a colour","")`

Where `Table1[Colours]` contains my list of colour text strings and `A1` contains my first product description.

(*Dave Bruns @ ExcelJet has a great [read](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things) for anyone wanting to use SUMPRODUCT/ISNUMBER/SEARCH combinations.*)

If a product description contains a colour specified in my `Table1[Colours]` list the formula produces `"Cannot include a colour"` to remind the user this is not allowed.

Example:
"Garmin Forerunner 10 Running Sportswatch **Green**"

The first issue i am faced with is that my current formula [proc](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Proc)s when the product description contains a compound word containing a colour...

Example:
"**Black**berry Z10 Smartphone"

This inaccurately invalidates the description because the string `"Black"` in this text is not being used to describe the colour of the product.

As the title suggests, my main issue lies with outsmarting 'complicated compound' words...

... my `Table1[Colours]` list does not simply contain the basic Primary, Secondary and Tertiary colours, but also more exotic ones like Coral, Fuchsia and Tan.

This causes complication when the product description contains a word like "Stand".

Why is this a problem you may be thinking? Stand contains one of my exotic colours 'Tan'

S-**Tan**-d

Unfortunately this also causes my formula to [proc](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Proc). (Annoying right?)

The solution I am looking for is an addition to my existing formula `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table1[Colors],A1)))>0,"Cannot include a colour","")` which accounts for the possible occurrence of a 'complicated compound' be this by a counter list of acceptable words (e.g. `Table2[Exceptions]` or by wild carding the search to match the exact colour with no Prefix or Suffix (this option would have to allow for the possibility of a dual colour separated by a `/` e.g. "Black/Red", so wild carding with certain punctuation exceptions?)

...Its all just a bit horrible and inconvenient.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks, Mr. J

Comment: The colors...Are they always at the end? just like "Garmin Forerunner 10 Running Sportswatch **Green**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to search for the word boundaries.  If you add a `space` to the beginning and end of the color, and also to the beginning and end of your description, that should do the trick depending on your data.  So the search part of your formula could read:

```
SEARCH(" " &Table1[Colors]& " "," "&A1&" ")
```

Or, for your entire formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&Table1[Colors]&" "," "&A1&" ")))>0,"Cannot include a colour","")
```

If you have hyphenated colors, e.g:  `blue-green`, or a color like `Cherry3`, you would need to list them separately in your table.

**EDIT**:  As your comment suggests a much more complex situation, I would suggest a User Defined Function (UDF) for ease of maintenance.

The following UDF can accept, as `findtext` a range, a single string, or an array constant consisting of several strings.  If you use an array constant, you must use the semicolon `;` and not a comma as the separator.

A usage example:

```
=IF(reMatch(Table1[Colors],A1),"Cannot include a colour","")
```

The code uses the Regex token for Word Boundary.  A word boundary is the point at which a character in the set `[0-9A-Za-z_]` is adjacent to any character not in that set, or next to the beginning or end of the string.  That should cover all of your `IF` function examples, and more.

```
Option Explicit
Function reMatch(FindText As Variant, WithinText As String) As Boolean
'FindText could be a Range, an array constant, or a single item
'If FindText is an array constant, separate elements by semicolons, not commas
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim I As Long
    Dim C As Range
    Dim vFind As Variant

reMatch = False
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True

    vFind = FindText  'will create array if FindText is a range
    If IsArray(vFind) Then
        For I = 1 To UBound(vFind)
            .Pattern = "\b" & vFind(I, 1) & "\b"
            If .Test(WithinText) = True Then
                reMatch = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next I
    Else
        .Pattern = "\b" & vFind & "\b"
        If .Test(WithinText) = True Then _
            reMatch = True
    End If
End With

End Function
```

**EDIT:** As written, `FindText` can be a range of cells; however, that range must be a single column vertical range.  If it is a horizontal range, the function will return the `#VALUE!` error. If necessary, the UDF could be modified to handle that by testing vFind and ensuring it is a 2D array. This would also enable the use of array constants with comma separators (the **additional** code is that which is seen between the first and last lines of code below.

```
...
vFind = FindText  'will create array if FindText is a range

'make sure vFind is 2D (if array)
On Error Resume Next
    J = UBound(vFind, 2)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then vFind = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vFind)
On Error GoTo 0

If IsArray(vFind) Then
...
```

Comment: Concatenating the SEARCH findtext and withintext with a space works really well! I have just extended my IF with a few more nested IFs to account for punctuation possibilities. The formula below covers (Black), Black/Red and (Black/Red). Crude, but it works. If I come across any other instances I will add additional nested IFs. Thanks @Ron

Comment: Formula for reference: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&Table1[Color name]&" "," "&A1&" ")))>0,"Cannot include colour",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/"&Table1[Color name]&"/","/"&A1&"/")))>0,"Cannot include colour",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("("&Table1[Color name],A1)))>0,"Cannot include colour",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table1[Color name]&")",A1)))>0,"Cannot include colour",""))))`

Comment: @Mr.J Rather than such a complex formula, I would suggest a VBA solution using Regular Expressions.  I will **Edit** my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: This is perfect and so much easier to manage. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: `vFind = FindText  'will create array if FindText is a range` that is one heck of a trick

Comment: @AndreTerra It is an adaptation of how one reads a range into a VBA array.  Basically   `v = myRange` will create a one-based 2D array where the first dimension denotes the rows, and the second the columns.  Provoked by your comment, I should add that the UDF as written will only work for vertical range arrays (and I should annotate that, which I did not).  But it could be modified to work for horizontal ranges (or even multiple rows and columns).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks. I just always struggle with making functions take either ranges or arrays (as I like to keep them flexible and the distinction is often unnecessary) so this seems like a great approach. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(  ($G$2:$G$159 >= $E$164) *  ($G$2:$G$159 <= $F$164 ) * (EXACT($E165,$F$2:$F$159)))
```

Better use "EXACT" instead of is number